# Does aws new VPC or routing table cost any thing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I created a VPC and a RT and a NACL too got created along with it?
I don't plan to use the VPC immediately but it will help me if its there for doing some study prior to creating further resources in it.

Does the current state of the VPC cost me anything. Should I delete it and recreate it when required for cost reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resources you mentioned specifically are free within a VPC (in fact AWS spawns a default VPC in each region within your AWS account).

There are however, a number of other VPC resources which do have a financial cost to launching them  such as NATs and VPNs. For more information take a look at the [Amazon VPC pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/) page.

Comment: There is no mention of RT pricing any where, so had to look at SOF. cool and tx.

Comment: No problem have a great day

Answer (score 1):

No. The [VPC itself is free](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/), including any RTs and NACLs. Like many AWS services, you only pay for underlying resources.

Comment: OP is asking whether routing table is one of such paid resources.

Comment: They specifically ask, "Does the current state of the VPC cost me anything", which it doesn't. I amended for clarity.